# Need a variable to refer back to Friday of last week

Tags: postgresql

In PostGresql, I'm looking for something that simply gets the date of Friday of the previous week, no matter what day I run the program on.

I've tried using the DATE_TRUNC() function:

```
DATE_TRUNC('DAY',NOW()) - INTERVAL '5 DAY' as LAST_CRED_DATE_CYCLE
```

But with this I have to change the INTERVAL depending on what day I run it.  I've tried other forms of the DATE_TRUNC and other functions but I just can't get there.  Is there a way to get last Friday's date no matter what day I run this code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Date_Trunc()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) is the function you are loooking for, you just have the wrong field. `Date_Trunc('week', <target_date>) always returns Monday of the week containing the target_date. From that subtracting 3 (for date) or interval` 3 days (for timestamp) will the give the prior Friday. Try

```
select date_trunc('week', current_date)::date - 3;
```

Comment: Yours was the most simple and accurate answer.  I will use this.  THANKS!  I've accepted it as my solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract last sunday and then remove 2 days to get last friday

```
select current_date - extract(dow from current_date)::integer -2 as LAST_CRED_DATE_CYCLE
```

| last_cred_date_cycle |
| --- |
| 2024-02-09 |

> ```
> SELECT 1
> ```

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('DAY',NOW()) - INTERVAL '1 DAY'
  * ((extract(dow from current_date)::integer ) + 2 ) as LAST_CRED_DATE_CYCLE
```

| last_cred_date_cycle |
| --- |
| 2024-02-09 00:00:00+00 |

> ```
> SELECT 1
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FRd9trPq)

Answer (score 0):

There's also [`date_bin()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-BIN): [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/FDAT1Kx7)

```
select date_bin('1 week',
                'today',
                '20240216')::date;
```

| date_bin |
| --- |
| 2024-02-09 |

Given any Friday as origin and a "bin size" of 1 week, it'll always give you last Friday.

Comment: 1st param is your bin size, 2nd is your target date where you put `now()` or `today`, 3rd is the origin.